# Is it grammatical to say that "a filter is ultra"?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, article-writing

In the same way that sometimes people will say, "our morphism $\phi$ is thus endo only if the image is normal..." or stuff like that -- basically transforming a prefix into an adjective -- is it reasonable to say that "our filter $D$ will be ultra as long as $X \subseteq \mathcal{N}(X)$" or "Every filter that is principal is also ultra"? I'm sure that people will have differing views here to some degree, so in order to keep things more objective: I guess I'm wondering if anyone has either a professional source "ultra" was used, or a situation where they used "ultra" and were called out on it.

Comment: This is the kind of behaviour that is only acceptable between consenting adults in private.

Comment: You wouldn't be the first person to do it. It's on page 89 of Thomas Forster, Logic, Induction and Sets, https://books.google.com.au/books?id=mVeTuaRwWssC&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=%22filter+is+ultra%22&source=bl&ots=6lY1Chu7bR&sig=ib-ZjgVkQd8p3Ffr9A6iNDf5E4Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtxLakqfTWAhWElZQKHXv6AIoQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=%22filter%20is%20ultra%22&f=false also Theorem 3.2.6 of Muraleetharan, Generalisations of Filters and Uniform Spaces, http://math.ucr.edu/~muralee/thesis-Rhodes.pdf (but that doesn't mean it's OK).

Comment: No. Filters are not ultra, morphisms are not endo, groups are not sub, orderings are not well, no matter who says so.

Comment: An ultrafilter is just a prime filter, isn't it? Why not just say the filter is prime?

Comment: Shouldn't the tag be "terminology" rather than "notation"?

Comment: @bof Yes, that's more appropriate tag, one that I was not aware of. I agree that groups are never "sub", because that's a term that only has meaning relative to something else: in the same way that it wouldn't make sense to describe the taste of some food, in isolation, as "sweeter". But for filters, orderings, and morphisms, the 'adjective' is an absolute statement of the item itself, without relevance to any other structure. As for why not saying that it's prime: well, I dunno, take that up with whatever branch rendered that terminology redundant :P but people talk about ultrafilters often.

Comment: "Sub" was a poor example. What about "semi"? Can a group be semi?

Comment: I have heard a professor tell a class of undergraduates that one should never say a sequence is Cauchy, although of course one can speak of a Cauchy sequence. The idea is that "Cauchy sequence" is a compound noun. "Classroom" is a compound noun and one doesn't say "This room is class", as if "class" were an adjective.

Comment: Only if your orem you proved this morning was the.